# How can I find the FB app owner, if I have only FB app key and secret?

Tags: account, secret-key

The problem is that we made that application long time ago and we don't know which account we used to create it. Now we need to update some configuration and all FB accounts I've tried are not managing that application.

Is there any way to find out the FB account name by FB applications key and secret, which we have stored in our ini file.

I know it's a weird situation, but I'll be really grateful for your help!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can. Create an `access_token` using the applications key and secret:

```
applicationKey|applicationSecret
```

Then use it to query the GraphAPI about itself:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{appId}?access_token={appId}|{appSecret}&fields=contact_email,creator_uid
```

Fill the URL with your values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key and secret to generate the access token. with the access token, user the facebook api to get the account information.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Or you can also check the test user to change anything.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/